# Ktor: HttpRequestTimeoutException when downloading file (but Chrome downloads successfully)

Tags: kotlin, timeout, httpclient, ktor-client

I'm encountering `io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestTimeoutException` errors when using Ktor to download a file from the public API endpoint `https://public.bybit.com/trading/10000000AIDOGEUSDT/10000000AIDOGEUSDT2024-03-05.csv.gz`.

Interestingly, I can download the same file successfully using a web browser like Chrome.

**Code Snippet**:

```
suspend fun downloadFile(
url: String,
destination: File
): File {
    val response = httpClient.get(url).bodyAsChannel()
    val sink = destination.writeChannel()
    response.copyTo(sink)
    sink.close()
    return destination
}

HttpClient(CIO) {
    this.install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(
            Json {
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
            }
        )
    }
    this.install(HttpTimeout) {
        requestTimeoutMillis = 20000
    }  
}
```

**Error**:

```
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-7" io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestTimeoutException: Request timeout has expired [url=https://public.bybit.com/trading/10000000AIDOGEUSDT/10000000AIDOGEUSDT2024-03-05.csv.gz, request_timeout=20000 ms]
at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpTimeout$Plugin$install$1$1$killer$1.invokeSuspend(HttpTimeout.kt:165)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@75171877, Dispatchers.IO]
```

**Problem**:

- The download consistently fails with `HttpRequestTimeoutException` despite having a 20-second timeout set.
- Downloading the same file from the same URL works using a web browser.

**Question**:

- What could be causing the `HttpRequestTimeoutException` when using `Ktor` to download the file, even though a web browser can download it successfully?
- Are there specific considerations or configurations I need to be aware of when downloading data using `Ktor`?
- Are there alternative approaches or troubleshooting steps I can try to overcome this timeout issue?